# Centering PickerIOS in React Native

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I have been trying to center a PickerIOS, but I am probably missing the underlying logic behind a Picker, because I just want its width to be full screen.

I can manage to do that with iPhone 4s / 5s, but when I run it on the iPhone 6, the Picker seems to be on the left, with some space on the right side.

I have been trying to use alignItem:'center' with a wrapper around the picker, but that just makes it disappear. I have also tried alignSelf, but still doesn't work.

I thought that Picker, by default, had its width to full screen or does it adapt according to the length of the elements?

Do I have to place it in a Flexbox in order to get it centered with a full screen width?

[image]

[image]

```
mask1: {
height:120,
overflow:'hidden',
justifyContent:'space-around',
marginTop:50
}
```

Comment: I have just edited my question.

Comment: Even if I set the width of the Picker to 1000, the space on the right side is still there, but the picker is clearly into anything. There is only a wrapper, which I am posting above, but removing the wrapper or adding it doesn't change the width problem.

Comment: Please post this a s issue on React-Native github page. Maybe someone would suggest a solution. I am facing this issue as well.. thx

Answer (score 2):

I find out that the style of PickerIOSItem cannot change, and only works fine in NavigatorIOS. I review the example of UIExplorer and there is no more style binding to the Item. Maybe it's a bug.